# Как сделать изменяемый заголовок в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Возможно ли сделать заголовок изменяемым, при открытии файла. К примеру при создании родительского окна сделать «название программы», а при загрузке какого-то файла, изменить текст в заголовке на «название программы - путь к загруженному файлу»

Answer (score 3):

Собственно, `root.title = build_new_title()` позволит изменить заголовок.

Думаю, правильный вопрос - как запускать это по определенным событиям?
В таком случае - собственно, смотреть в следующую сторону, видимо : http://younglinux.info/tkinter/event.php

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы все правильно поняли.

Answer (score 1):

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.title = "bla-bla-bla"
```

Comment: Видимо Вы не совсем поняли, что я имею в виду. Представьте к примеру текстовый редактор. При запуске в заголовке надпись «Блокнот», Вы нажимаете пункт меню открыть файл, выбираете файл для открытия и после его загрузки в виджет ScrolledText заголовок окна меняется на «Блокнот - путь к файлу»

Comment: Нет, не понимаю. Поставьте вопрос более развернуто. Вы что, хотите изменить заголовок системной программы с помощью Tkinter?

Comment: Если у вас стоит windows запустите блокнот. В заголовке будет надпись «Безымянный - Блокнот». Нажмите открыть файл и выберите любой текстовый файл, заголовок измениться на «Название файла - Блокнот», вот такое мне и нужно реализовать в tkinter'e.

Comment: Вопрос не ясен! Ибо в моем первом ответе приведен рецепт изменения заголовка окон Tkinter! У меня Linux, и я совершенно не понимаю, при чем здесь блокнот!? Поставьте корректно задачу,  например "Изменение заголовка окна Tk в Tkinter" или "Изменение заголовков системных программ с помощью Tkinter"! Иначе ответов вы не дождетесь...

Answer (score 0):

Вот Вам примерчик изменения заголовка по нажатию разных кнопок. В рамках Ваших событий необходимо изменять **root.title('')**.

```
import tkinter as tk
root=tk.Tk()
root.title("Изначальное название заголовка")
root.geometry("250x80")

def name1():
    root.title("Первое название")

def name2():
    root.title("Второе название")


button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Меняем название на 1',font=('clearlyu', 10), command=name1)
button2 = tk.Button(root, text='Меняем название на ',font=('clearlyu', 10), command=name2)

button1.pack()
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы очень непонятно cформулировали свой вопрос.

Очевидно,что никто вам не напишет дополнительный параметр или встроеннyю функцию,kоторая бы понималa,что вы открываете файл и озаглавливала бы окно соответствующим названием.Вы сами должны написать для этого код.

Вот пример простейшего обозревателя текстовых файлов,который меняет заголовок окна на путь к файлу с помощью метода title:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
root=Tk()
root.iconify()
default_title='Средство просмотра текстовых файлов'
def open_file(path=None):
    top=Toplevel(root)
    if path:
        top.title(default_title+' - '+path) #Та самая строка
        file=open(path,encoding='utf-8')
        ent=Text(top)
        ent.place(relwidth=1,relheight=1)
        ent.insert(END,file.read())
        file.close()
    else:
        top.title(default_title)
    top.geometry('800x600')
    menu=Menu(top)
    top['menu']=menu
    filemenu=Menu(menu,tearoff=False)
    menu.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)
    def choose_file():
        path=askopenfilename(filetypes=[("text files", ".txt")])
        if path:
            open_file(path)
    filemenu.add_command(label='Open',command=choose_file)
open_file()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, что файл с текстом сохраняется через функцию `xSaveAs`:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename 

def xSaveAs(): 
    filepath = asksaveasfilename( 
        defaultextension=".txt", 
        filetypes=[
            ("Текстовые файлы", "*.txt"), 
            ("Все файлы", "*.*"), 
            ("Файлы Python", "*.py"), 
        ], 
    ) 
    if not filepath: return 
    xfile = open(filepath, "w") 
    xfile.write(appText.get("1.0", tk.END))
        # Здесь appText - поле с текстом прораммы
```

Тогда заголовок можно изменить внутри функции через **app.title()** 
и свойством **title** у **asksaveasfilename**:

```
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename 

def xSaveAs(): 
    filepath = asksaveasfilename( 
        title="Блокнот - Сохранить как", 
            # Изменение заголовка окна выбора файла
        defaultextension=".txt", 
        filetypes=[
            ("Текстовые файлы", "*.txt"), 
            ("Все файлы", "*.*"), 
            ("Файлы Python", "*.py"), 
        ], 
    ) 
    if not filepath: return 
    xfile = open(filepath, "w") 
    xfile.write(appText.get("1.0", tk.END))
        # *Здесь appText - поле с текстом прораммы
    app.title(f"Блокнот - {filepath}") 
        # Изменение заголовка родительского окна*
        # *Здесь app - окно прораммы
```